# Unrcognizable symbols ï»¿ when using python to read vb file

Tags: python, python-3.x, vb.net, readfile, readline

There is a `.vb` file, when I can read the content of this file if add not recognizable symbols `ï»¿` in the beginning of the file like below:

```
ï»¿Imports XYZDAL.AddressTableAdapters
```

while this file onyk contains:

```
Imports XYZDAL.AddressTableAdapters
```

This is python script that I am using to read the file:

```
f = open(file_name, "r")
while True:
    line = f.readline()
```

What is this symbol and how can I avoid it?

Comment: What is the text encoding of the `.vb` file?

Comment: That looks like the UTF-8 encoding mark (sometimes called a "byte-order mark" even though UTF-8 is only a single-byte encoding so there is no byte order, the name carries over from two-byte and four-byte encodings where the order is significant).

Comment: [Built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) => `f = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`. @Craig *UTF-8 is only a single-byte encoding*? The BOM in UTF-8 is not required because the bits order also determines the sequence an there's no *endianness*. The BOM is used as a signature or *magic numbers* by software that can read multiple encodings and don't implement heuristics to discover the encoding (which takes time). But, single-byte encoding...

Comment: @Jimi Maybe the way to put it is that unlike UCS-2, UTF-16, or UTF-32, the size of the addressable units in the stream (which may be code points as they are, or combined with one or more subsequent units to form a code point) is a byte, so there is no issue with the arrangement of bytes within a unit.  In the other unicode schemes I mentioned, the mark doesn't just signify the encoding, it also signifies the ordering of the bytes within the unit, thus "byte order mark."  (I'm probably using the wrong term of art for a unit here.)